# How do i catch FunctionTimeoutException in my durable azure function orchestrator

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs

I am having issues catching the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException exception in my orchestrator code. I call an activity function a couple of times in my orchestrator code asynchronously and sometimes, one or more of the calls times out due to my functionTimeout settings of 10 minutes: 00:10:00. I however still want to process successful calls so, i wrap my call in a try..catch block as shown below. However, whenever one of the calls times out, the whole function fails and never continues past the catch block. Am i doing something wrong? Is there no way to catch this exception in code?

```
foreach (var x in list)
{                 
    tasks.Add(context.CallActivityAsync<ProcessorExecutionResult> 
    ("RunChecksForX", new XProcessingInput
    {
        a= a,
        SessionId = context.InstanceId
    }));
}
try
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
var successfulTasks = tasks.Where(task => task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion);
var results = new List<ProcessorExecutionResult>();
results.AddRange(successfulTasks.Select(async x => await x).Select(x => x.Result));
```

I expect the exception to be caught and processing should continue after the try..catch block but the function shuts down instead.

```
2023-02-11T11:52:58Z   [Error]   Timeout value of 00:10:00 exceeded by function 'RunChecksForX' (Id: 'db181d18-17dc-41ec-887d-905b78424930'). Initiating cancellation.
2023-02-11T11:52:58Z   [Error]   Executed 'RunChecksForX' (Failed, Id=db181d18-17dc-41ec-887d-905b78424930, Duration=600137ms)
2023-02-11T11:52:58Z   [Error]   A function timeout has occurred. Host is shutting down.
2023-02-11T11:52:58Z   [Error]   2ff9c1a8669c495abc7e951e93c4e3cd: Function 'RunChecksForX (Activity)' failed with an error. Reason: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionTimeoutException: Timeout value of 00:10:00 was exceeded by function: RunChecksForX
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryHandleTimeoutAsync(Task invokeTask, CancellationToken shutdownToken, Boolean throwOnTimeout, CancellationToken timeoutToken, TimeSpan timeoutInterval, IFunctionInstance instance, Action onTimeout) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 663
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeWithTimeoutAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource, Boolean throwOnTimeout, TimeSpan timerInterval, IFunctionInstance instance) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 571
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 527
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 306
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(IFunctionInstanceEx instance, FunctionStartedMessage message, FunctionInstanceLogEntry instanceLogEntry, ParameterHelper parameterHelper, ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 352
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:line 108. IsReplay: False. State: Failed. HubName: xfuncdevabc. AppName: xfunc-dev-abc. SlotName: Production. ExtensionVersion: 2.9.1. SequenceNumber: 61. TaskEventId: 6

2023-02-11T11:52:58Z   [Information]   2ff9c1a8669c495abc7e951e93c4e3cd: Task activity [RunDataQualityChecksForBusinessFunction] failed: FailureSource:
```

Answer (score 1):

- Well if your are catching function timeout specifically then you will have to use the Timers.
- Conceptually here we are creating a timer task which will basically count till the said number of time and then check whether the timer task executed first or the activity task.
- Then depending upon the which execute the first we can dictate the next course of action just like a try catch block.
- Consider the following orchestrator function:

```
public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    // The below is bascally used to create the timer
    // you can edit the .FromSeconds() function
    // to configure the limit of your 
    // function execution time
    
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    DateTime deadline = context.CurrentUtcDateTime.Add(timeout);

    var outputs = new Task<string>[3];
    for(int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
    {
        // Here we are using Cancellation tokens
        using ( var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            // First we call the task
            Task<string> CurrentActivity = context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo");
            
            // Then we are creating the timer
            Task timeoutTask = context.CreateTimer(deadline, cts.Token);

            // Now we will check which executes first
            Task winner = await Task.WhenAny(CurrentActivity, timeoutTask);
            
            // Now the winner is task which finished first
             if (winner == CurrentActivity)
                    {
                        outputs[i] = CurrentActivity;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // This will execute if function timeout happens
                        
                        outputs[i] = CurrentActivity; 
                        
                        Console.WriteLine("TimeoutException has Happened");
                    }
             
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

- Here I am delaying the activity function by 2 sec using   `Thread.Sleep(2000)`and it is catching Timeout exception

  [image]

Comment: I want to run those requests together and not wait for one to finish before running the next. Also, your code will still throw the FunctionTimeoutException and shut down the run.